# How to find the mean after dropping rows with NA in R

Tags: r

I have checked other posts to find the method of how to drop the rows with NAs in R, but I cannot operate anything after that(for example finding the mean)

[image]

Comment: In the future, it is better to show the example data using `dput` as we cannot copy data from image for testing.

Comment: Please consider reading up on [ask] and how to produce a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 2):

The reason is because the 'x' and 'y' column could be `factor` class.  We can change it to `numeric` and it should work

```
mean(as.numeric(as.character(test2$x)), na.rm=TRUE)
#[1] 300
```

It happens, when there are non-numeric elements already present in the dataset and we use `read.csv/read.table` to read the dataset with the default option `stringsAsFactors=TRUE`.  So, any column that have non-numeric would be a `factor`.  Even if, we use `stringsAsFactors=FALSE`, the column would be `character` and using `mean` directly on `character` class will give the same NA as result

```
mean(as.character(test2$y), na.rm=TRUE)
#[1] NA
#Warning message:
#In mean.default(as.character(test2$y), na.rm = TRUE) :
#  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

We can check the `str(test2)` and find the `class` or use `class(test2$x)`

#### data

```
test <- data.frame(x= c(124, "*", 546, 54), y = c("*", 
    2, 34, 4), z =c(324, 354, 12, 54), b = c(133, 54, 11, 545))
test[test=="*"] <- NA
test2 <- na.omit(test)
```